# Checkout with a single product: verify if ANY product is in the cart, and give error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I can't imagine how to verify if the cart has some products inside, or not. I just need to allow ONE product for the checkout.

Here is the code used in class-wc-cart.php to prevent products to be added if THE SAME product is already in the cart, and I'm sure should be pretty similar, but I'm missing some WP variables to define any kind of product.
I tried also with [this code](http://www.remicorson.com/limit-number-of-products-to-add-to-the-shop), but it doesn't work in functions.php (no, I'm not using child themes).

```
if ( $product_data->is_sold_individually() ) {
            $in_cart_quantity = $cart_item_key ? $this->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['quantity'] : 0;

            // If it's greater than 0, it's already in the cart
            if ( $in_cart_quantity > 0 ) {
                wc_add_notice( sprintf(
                    '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s',
                    $this->get_cart_url(),
                    __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ),
                    sprintf( __( 'You cannot add another &quot;%s&quot; to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_title() )
                ), 'error' );
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to limit the cart to only 1 item *total* or just to a single quantity of a particular item? (If the latter, just set the item to be sold individually)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Woocommerce to only allow 1 product in the cart. If a product is already in the cart and another 1 is added then it should remove the previous 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363268/need-woocommerce-to-only-allow-1-product-in-the-cart-if-a-product-is-already-in)

Comment: Though technically a duplicate, I don't love the answer. I have provided an snippet that I have used on occasion as I think the validation filter is a better place to add the functionality you are requesting.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make changes directly in woocommerce core file because when you update plugin, might your code lost.

Add following code into functions.php and it will add only one product into cart:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom' );

function woocommerce_add_cart_item_data_custom( $cart_item_data ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    if($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count > 0){
         wc_add_notice(
                     __( 'You cannot add another product to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ));

                return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very good and simple! It works, but it's so strong that I can't add error messages (like 'hey, you can't add more then one single product in cart!'), or it is printed out also if there are no products and you're adding one to cart for the first time