# How to skip "You cannot add another to your cart" Error in woocommerce and directly jump to Checkout?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, storefront

What Woocommerce Does is...

When products are Sold Individually, and when the product already exists in the Cart and customer clicks on Add to Cart, Woocommerce shows Error Message "You cannot add another to your cart.....View Cart"

Instead of the above flow I want..

When customer clicks on Add to Cart and if the product already exists in the Cart then woocommerce should redirect to Checkout page straightway.

I think this can be achieved by editing few lines of code in class-wc-cart.php of Woocommerce Plugin.

The is given below:

```
// Force quantity to 1 if sold individually and check for existing item in cart
                if ( $product_data->is_sold_individually() ) {
                    $quantity         = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_quantity', 1, $quantity, $product_id, $variation_id, $cart_item_data );
                    $in_cart_quantity = $cart_item_key ? $this->cart_contents[ $cart_item_key ]['quantity'] : 0;

                    if ( $in_cart_quantity > 0 ) {
                        throw new Exception( sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', wc_get_cart_url(), __( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ), sprintf( __( 'You cannot add another &quot;%s&quot; to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_title() ) ) );
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checkout with a single product: verify if ANY product is in the cart, and give error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030769/checkout-with-a-single-product-verify-if-any-product-is-in-the-cart-and-give-e)

Comment: My issue is a bit different from the one marked as Possible Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030769/checkout-with-a-single-product-verify-if-any-product-is-in-the-cart-and-give-e

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking into how to do this myself. **user1072884's** answer is okay, however, it only works for one productID at a time. Not ideal if you have multiple products.

Here's a simplified solution that will work for all products.

Simply add the following code to your child theme functions.php and swap the placeholder text with your checkout page URL.

```php
/** If multiple items are in the cart redirect to the checkout page instead of throwing an error **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_cart' );
function check_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count > 0 ) {
        $direct_url = home_url( 'xyz' ); // Change the value of your actual redirect url.
        wp_redirect( $direct_url );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Old thread, but maybe someone else will find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_quantity', 'vipcomment_change_quantity_to_zero', 10, 5 );
function vipcomment_change_quantity_to_zero( $one, $quantity, $product_id, $variation_id, $cart_item_data ) {
    $your_product_id = 96;
    if ( $product_id == $your_product_id ) {
        $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
        $in_cart         = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
        if ( $in_cart ) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return $quantity;
        }
    } else {
        return $quantity;
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart', 'vipcomment_is_product_exist_in_cart', 10, 5 );
function vipcomment_is_product_exist_in_cart( $exist, $product_id, $variation_id, $cart_item_data, $cart_id ) {
    $your_product_id = 96;
    if ( $product_id == $your_product_id ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $exist;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_quantity', 'vipcomment_change_quantity_to_zero', 10, 5 );
function vipcomment_change_quantity_to_zero( $one, $quantity, $product_id, $variation_id, $cart_item_data ) {
    $your_product_id = 3368;
    if ( $product_id == $your_product_id ) {
        $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
        $in_cart         = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
        if ( $in_cart ) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return $quantity;
        }
    } else {
        return $quantity;
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_sold_individually_found_in_cart', 'vipcomment_is_product_exist_in_cart', 10, 5 );
function vipcomment_is_product_exist_in_cart( $exist, $product_id, $variation_id, $cart_item_data, $cart_id ) {
    $your_product_id = 3368;
    if ( $product_id == $your_product_id ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $exist;
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', function( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
});
```

Visit https://www.tutorialslides.com/how-to-redirect-to-checkout-page-directly-instead-of-cart-page-in-wordpress
for detailed code

Answer (score -2):

Simplest way would be:

```
throw new Exception( sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', 
  wc_get_cart_url(), __( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), 
  header( "Location: https://www.example.com/cart/" ) ) );
```

instead of that error. Be advised: this will redirect the user to the cart page ( where the product should already be in place ).