# Capping number of items in woocommerce cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shopping-cart

I'm wanting to limit the number of products in my cart to **6 maximum**.
All products in my woocommerce setup are sold singularly (cannot buy multiples of the same product).

**Example of Cart**

[image: eXAMPLE]

Is there a way of limiting the cart to 6 products? So if the user goes to add a 7th, a warning will pop-up 'Maximum of 6 products only. Please remove a product from your cart'?

Tried googling, but could only find this, limited to a singular product: [Need Woocommerce to only allow 1 product in the cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363268/need-woocommerce-to-only-allow-1-product-in-the-cart-if-a-product-is-already-in)

Comment: Take a look at the get_cart_contents_count hook on the WooCommerce API at http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#338-345

You may be able to use this to return a warning message/value to the customer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same procedure as the other question you linked to. On the validation filter, check the cart contents, and return a message if your requirements aren't met. As mentioned, you would indeed use `get_cart_contents_count()` to count the number of line items in the cart.

**Edited:** remove `empty()` check on cart

```
function so_31516355_cap_cart_count( $valid, $product_id, $quantity ) {

    if( $valid && ( $quantity > 6 || intval( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) > 6 || $quantity + intval( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) > 6  ) ){
        $valid = false;
        wc_add_notice( 'Whoa hold up. You can only have 6 items in your cart', 'error' );
    }

    return $valid;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_31516355_cap_cart_count', 10, 3 );
```

**Added:** validation on cart update

```
function so_31516355_cap_cart_count_update( $valid, $cart_item_key, $values, $quantity ) {
    if( $valid && ( $quantity > 6 || intval( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) > 6 || $quantity + intval( WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) > 6  ) ){
        $valid = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Whoa hold up. You can only have 6 items in your cart', 'your-plugin' ), 'error' );
    }

    return $valid;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_update_cart_validation', 'so_31516355_cap_cart_count_update', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Sorry I could not get this to work... I was probably doing something wrong. Just got Blank screen. Ended up buying a plugin. Many thanks for your time :-)

Comment: If you get a blank screen it just means that there was a typo/syntax error and you could use [WP_DEBUG](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) mode to determine the location of the typo. I just tested and didn't see any debug errors, so the source of your white screen may have been elsewhere. I did forget to take into account the quantity being added so have updated my answer and can confirm that it works.

Comment: This code works, but there is a problem - **you can still change items count in cart page**, this filter does not apply there. I simply removed the quantity input field (see `woocommerce_cart_item_quantity` filter). Or better - show quantity as number, not HTML input field.

Comment: Ha, correction - this code works only when there is at least one item in cart! If cart is empty, you can add as many items as you want. It's because of `&& ! empty ( WC()->cart->get_cart() )` part - it will return `false` for empty cart, so no other check is made afterwards.

Comment: To change items in your cart, you need to also use the `woocommerce_update_cart_validation` filter. I've added that. And thanks for the correction on `empty()`, I've removed that.