# woocommerce - only allow 1 item in cart and add current item by replacing the older item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to limit the cart to only 1 item.
If the user has 0 items in the cart it will add the item to the cart.

If the user has the previous item in the cart then it must be replaced the current item.

PS: I found a similar question but no answer for it.
[WooCommerce: Only 1 product in cart. Replace if one is added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528781/woocommerce-only-1-product-in-cart-replace-if-one-is-added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );

function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This simple functionality plugin should do the job:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'limit_cart_to_one_item' );
function limit_cart_to_one_item( $cart_items ) {
    WC()->cart->empty_cart();
    return $cart_items;
}
```

Paste it in your theme functions.php file as explained here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-to-pasting-snippets-from-the-web-into-wordpress/

Cheers,
Francesco